# What happen to all the games on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

My Windows Vista machine has no games on it, I thought Microsoft had dropped the free games, however my wife’s Windows 7 machine has games on it.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft did not "drop" the free games in Vista.
You most likely just have them disabled, here's how to enable them:

1. Click the start button
2. Click Control Panel
3. Click the icon for Programs and Features
4. Look for the link on the left side of the page with the colored shield that says “Turn Windows Features On or Off” and click it
5. Click continue when prompted for permission
6. Check the box beside the folder labeled Games
7. Click OK and the installation of the games folder will be started.